By the time+ past perfect
We could say

I had cooked by the time she came

Could we also use the continuous version and say:
2 I had been cooking by the time she came ?

Please use the "edit" button to explain more. Questions that simply ask "is this ok?" only get very simple yes-or-no answers. If you explain your thinking a bit more, we can talk more about the right or wrong ideas.

@AndyBonner .Just some people told me that I can use the continuous versions with "by the time" and some that I can't. So, that's why I'm asking to make sure who told me the truth

Example (1) is actually a little strange. "Cooking" is an action that takes some time, unlike an instantaneous action such as turning on a TV. I had turned on the TV by the time she came. sounds normal, but if you say "I had cooked" it isn't clear if you just started the action or completely finished it.

Thanks! But please use the "edit" button to add to the question itself, not just a comment. And if you can quote the advice you got that might let us talk about whether it was good or bad. This sentence isn't a good fit for the continuous, but some other situation could be.



I had cooked by the time she came
Could we also use the continuous version and say:
I had been cooking by the time she came ?


I understand that OP wants to know how to use the forms of the past tense.
I'm writing OP's lines in the past tense in multiple forms.Please see whether it is helpful.

Simple past tense.
I finished cooking before she came.
Past continuous tense
I was cooking when she came.
Past perfect tense.
I had finished cooking when she arrived.
Past perfect continuous tense.
I had been cooking for two hours when she came.

Please note that cooking is a gerund in sentences 1 & 3.
